# Get specific data from string

Tags: php, string

I want to get the following data "PHPSESSID" from this script in a string:

```
<?php    
file_get_contents('https://www.bedandbreakfast.nl/?page=ajaxcb&do=updateBookingIntent&arrival=2015-08-22&departure=2015-08-23&src=booking_arrival');

$cookies = array();
foreach ($http_response_header as $hdr) {
    if (preg_match('/^Set-Cookie:\s*([^;]+)/', $hdr, $matches)) {
        parse_str($matches[1], $tmp);
        $cookies += $tmp;
    }
}
print_r($cookies);
?>
```

I tried to run this script, only that wasn't working...

```
echo $cookies[PHPSESSID];
```

Comment: Re-opened as not a duplicate of the linked question.

Comment: String: `$data = "Array ( [PHPSESSID] => infodata)";` array: `$data = Array ( "PHPSESSID" => "infodata");`

Comment: To give something of an answer to the question: if you want to access an array, it would be helpful if you actually had an array to start with.

Comment: Full code is uploaded now ;)

Comment: Your code makes no sense. You don't assign the return value of `file_get_contents()` nowhere.

Comment: @Rizier123: Your dupehammer is a privilege. Please don't abuse it.

Comment: And what is `$http_response_header`? This code is indeed complete nonsense.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit In OP's first revision he just asked how to access an array element and my dupe **exactly** showed how to do that! At this point he also showed a **real** array and not a string.

Comment: @Rizier123: Er, granted, the OP has _completely_ changed the question. WTF.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit How should I know that he will change his question completely 2 times after I closed it with the dupe?

Comment: So do we make any progress with this question? 1) Where does `$http_response_header` come from? 2) What is the **exact** output of: `print_r($cookies);` ? 3) Do you get any errors?(Turn error reporting on: `<?php
  ini_set("display_errors", 1);
  error_reporting(E_ALL);
 ?>`) 4) What do you get with: `echo $cookies[PHPSESSID];` 4.1) Is `PHPSESSID` really a constant or should it be a string?

Comment: @Rizier123: You can't. That's why I said "granted". OP's a loon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This one works:

```
file_get_contents('https://www.bedandbreakfast.nl/?page=ajaxcb&do=updateBookingIntent&arrival=2015-08-22&departure=2015-08-23&src=booking_arrival');
foreach ($http_response_header as $header) {
    if (substr($header, 0, 21) == 'Set-Cookie: PHPSESSID') {
        preg_match('/=([a-z0-9]+);/', $header, $matches);
        $sessionId = $matches[1];
        echo $sessionId;
    }
}
```